# :not(:hover) not working with opacity

Tags: javascript, css

I have the following code:

```
#topbar:not(:hover){
  -skrollr-animation-name: topbaropa;
}
#topbar:hover {
  -skrollr-animation-name: topbarhoveropa;

}
```

It's supposed to fade the opacity of `#topbar` when scrolling gradually to 0.10, but when you hover `#topbar` the opacity goes back to 1, then mouse off goes back to 0.10.

The problem is, it doesn't work. It fades while scrolling, but doesn't go back to 1 on mouseover.

I've also tried instead of `#topbar:hover { -skrollr-animation` just using `opacity: 1` but that doesn't work either =/

If anyone wants to actually see what I mean the link is http://pattersoncode.ca/new%20design/?a=help

Comment: What is `-skrollr-` prefix?

Comment: @Passerby It's a jQuery script to add css styles when scrolling

Comment: But I don't see it being "corrected" in Chrome DevTool, so if it's supposed to work in your expected way, it's pure JS, not CSS. It would be nice if you can make a fiddle to demonstrate the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply added a class on hover, and removed the class on mouse off.

Answer (score 1):

`skrollr-stylesheets` does **not** support interaction.

> skrollr-stylesheets does not react to changes in the document. The stylesheets are parsed once and then applied. You can't add a class to an element and expect the keyframes to get updated.

https://github.com/Prinzhorn/skrollr-stylesheets#limitations